# send the output of exec in node.js to postman after it ends

Tags: node.js, express, postman, child-process

in postman I'm sending a request to my express server , that should execute a system command and store the output in a variable, and only after the child process is finished that I want to recieve the response containing the output of the exec function in postman.

```
app.post('/exploit', function(request, response) {            
  var script = request.body.script;
  var command = " msfconsole -q -r ~/Desktop/automation/meterpreter.rc ;                    
  python "+script;
   var child = exec(command);
        child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            data=data.toString();
            scriptOutput+=data;

    });
    function finaloutput() {
        response.end(scriptOutput);
      }
    setTimeout(finaloutput, 180000);
     });
```

the problem is that no matter what I try postman either blocks , or only prints the first line of the output, or shows an error message indicating that it could not get any response from the server.

Comment: Please show the code for the whole request handler.  This is not the proper way to use `exec()` in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your request handler is dangerous.  You're allowing unsanitized user input to be put directly on a command line.

Second, you're using `exec()` in the manner one would use `spawn()`, not how you use `exec()`.  Exec buffers all the output, waits until the program is done and then gives you all the output at once like this:

```
app.post('/exploit', function(request, response) {
    // note this is dangerous to put unsanitized user input directly onto the command line
    var script = request.body.script;
    var command = " msfconsole -q -r ~/Desktop/automation/meterpreter.rc ; python " + script;
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            response.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
            response.send(stdout);
        }
    });
});
```